# Unable to override port values using kustomization in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am doing some practices. one of the test cases i tried to override the values of port value. while doing that getting an error as **replace operation does not apply: doc is missing key: /spec/ports/port: missing value.**

```
patches:
  - target:
      kind: Service
      name: cdq-ui-service
    patch: |
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/ports/0/port
        value: 8080
```

while applying kustomization in Kubernetes with the patch. that path will be override the port value.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Include the content of your `kustomization.yaml` in the question, as text, formatted as a code sample. I've fixed this question for you, but please keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify `/spec/ports/port`, but there is no such path in a Kubernetes service. Recall that a service looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

The path `/spec/ports` is a **list**, not a **dictionary**. You could patch `/spec/ports/0/port`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- service.yaml

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Service
      name: my-service
    patch: |
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/ports/0/port
        value: 8080
```

Which would result in:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
```

Comment: Thanks its worked, I have small confusion about it, why should we mention 0 in that path.

Comment: Because your are modifying the first element of a list.